# Proof of weird formula for method of differences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, finite-differences

Suppose we have to find sum of a sequence $t_1,t_2,t_3...t_n$.

For $1\le i\le n$, let $\triangle t_i=t_{i+1} -t_i$, $\triangle ^2t_i=\triangle t_{i+1}-\triangle t_i$ and so on ($\triangle ^{j}t_i=\triangle^{j-1} t_{i+1}-\triangle^{j-1} t_i$).

My book gives the formula for the $j$th term and sum $S_n$ of the sequence as:

$$
t_j =
{}^{j-1}C_0\, t_1 + {}^{j-1}C_1\, \triangle t_1
 + {}^{j-1}C_2\, \triangle^2 t_1
 + \cdots + {}^{j-1}C_{j-1}\, \triangle^{j-1} t_1
$$
and
$$
S_n =\sum_{j=1}^nt_j=
{}^nC_1\, t_1 + {}^nC_2\, \triangle t_1 + {}^nC_3\, \triangle^2 t_1
 + \cdots + {}^nC_n\, \triangle^{n-1} t_1.
$$

(See the equations [as printed in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W7wZ.jpg).)

How to prove this? Any reference is appreciated.

P.S- Sorry for the image, as I could not typeset the entire equation in Latex.

Comment: What is $S_n$ a sum of? Your $\Delta^2$ is the same as your $\Delta$ too?

Comment: Have you checked that it is true for $n=1,2,3$? Do you know anything about induction?

Comment: I was very careful in converting the picture to Mathjax, and in the process already I can see inconsistencies. The superscript of $\triangle$ is less than the subscript of $C$ in the first three terms of $S_n$ but equal in the last term. And what is $r$?

Comment: I think I see the symbol "$\therefore$" in the book, indicating that these equations are the result of a preceding argument. (The symbol "$\therefore$" can be read "therefore".) It seems likely that the answer is actually in the book just before the part you included in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the well-known notation
$\newcommand{\mbin}[2]{{\small{\binom{#1}{#2}}}}{\displaystyle\mbin ab}$
instead of $\displaystyle{}^aC_b$ because I find it more readable, especially in combination with other symbols that have subscripts and superscripts.

If we define $\triangle^0\, t_i = t_i$
and $\triangle^1\, t_i = \triangle t_i$,
your definition says that
$$
\triangle^{k+1}\, t_i = \triangle^k\, t_{i+1} - \triangle^k\, t_i
$$
for integers $i \geq 1$ and $k\geq 0$.

Equivalently,
$$
\triangle^k\, t_{i+1} = \triangle^k\, t_i + \triangle^{k+1}\, t_i. \tag1
$$

It will be useful to define $\triangle^{-1}\, t_1 = 0$ and
$$
\triangle^{-1}\, t_i = \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} t_j
$$
for any integer $i > 1$. If we do that, then Equation $(1)$ is true for all integers $i \geq 1$ and $k\geq -1$.

We can apply Equation $(1)$ multiple times for other subscripts/superscripts:
\begin{align}
\triangle^k\, t_{i+2} &= \triangle^k\, t_{i+1} + \triangle^{k+1}\, t_{i+1} \\
&=\left(\triangle^k\, t_i + \triangle^{k+1}\, t_i\right)
  + \left(\triangle^{k+1}\, t_i + \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i\right) \\
&= \triangle^k\, t_i + 2 \triangle^{k+1}\, t_i + \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\triangle^k\, t_{i+3} &= \triangle^k\, t_{i+2} + \triangle^{k+1}\, t_{i+2} \\
&=\left(\triangle^k\, t_i + 2 \triangle^{k+1}\, t_i
           + \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i\right)
  + \left(\triangle^{k+1}\, t_i + 2 \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i
           + \triangle^{k+3}\, t_i\right) \\
&= \triangle^k\, t_i + 3 \triangle^{k+1}\, t_i + 3 \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i
     + \triangle^{k+3}\, t_i.
\end{align}

Do you recognize the pattern? It is
$$
\triangle^k\, t_{i+r} =
 \mbin r0 \triangle^k\, t_i + \mbin r1 \triangle^{k+1}\, t_i
   + \mbin r2 \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i + \cdots 
   + \mbin rr \triangle^{k+r}\, t_i. \tag2
$$

We can prove this by induction on $r$. The base case is for $r = 0$,
$$
\triangle^k\, t_{i+r} = \mbin 00 \triangle^k\, t_{i}
$$
for any $i \geq 1$ and any $k \geq -1$.
For the inductive step, assume Equation $(2)$ is true for a certain non-negative integer $r$. Then
\begin{align}
\triangle^k\, t_{i+r+1}
&= \triangle^k\, t_{i+r} + \triangle^{k+1}\, t_{i+r} \\
&= \mbin r0 \triangle^k\, t_i + \mbin r1 \triangle^{k+1}\, t_i
   + \mbin r2 \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i + \cdots 
   + \mbin rr \triangle^{k+r}\, t_i \\
& \qquad + \mbin r0 \triangle^{k+1}\, t_i + \mbin r1 \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i
   + \mbin r2 \triangle^{k+3}\, t_i + \cdots 
   + \mbin rr \triangle^{k+r+1}\, t_i \\
&= \triangle^k\, t_i
   + \left(\!\mbin r0 + \mbin r1\!\right)\triangle^{k+1}\,t_i
   + \left(\!\mbin r1 + \mbin r2\!\right) \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i + \cdots 
   + \triangle^{k+r+1}\, t_i \\
&= \mbin {r+1}0 \triangle^k\, t_i + \mbin {r+1}1 \triangle^{k+1}\,t_i
   + \mbin {r+1}2 \triangle^{k+2}\, t_i + \cdots
  + \mbin {r+1}{r+1} \triangle^{k+r+1}\, t_i.
\end{align}
That completes the induction.

Now that we have the formula in Equation $(2)$, we can simply apply it to the original question by choosing suitable values of $i$, $k$, and $r$.

With $i = 1$, $k = 0$, $r = n - 1$:

\begin{align}
t_n &= \triangle^0\, t_{1+(n-1)}\\
&= \mbin {n-1}0 \triangle^0\, t_1 + \mbin {n-1}1 \triangle^{0+1}\, t_1
   + \mbin {n-1}2 \triangle^{0+2}\, t_1 + \cdots 
   + \mbin {n-1}{n-1} \triangle^{0+n-1}\, t_1 \\
&= \mbin {n-1}0 t_1 + \mbin {n-1}1 \triangle t_1
   + \mbin {n-1}2 \triangle^2\, t_1 + \cdots 
   + \mbin {n-1}{n-1} \triangle^{n-1}\, t_1.
\end{align}

With $i = 1$, $k = -1$, $r = n$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n t_j &= \triangle^{-1}\, t_{1+n} \\
&= \mbin n0 \triangle^{-1}\, t_1 + \mbin n1 \triangle^{-1+1}\, t_1
   + \mbin n2 \triangle^{-1+2}\, t_1 \\ & \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
   + \mbin n3 \triangle^{-1+3}\, t_1 + \cdots 
   + \mbin nn \triangle^{-1+n}\, t_1 \\
&= \mbin n0\cdot 0 + \mbin n1 \triangle^0 t_1
   + \mbin n2 \triangle^1\, t_1 + \mbin n3 \triangle^2\, t_1 + \cdots 
   + \mbin nn \triangle^{n-1}\, t_1 \\
&= \mbin n1  t_1
   + \mbin n2 \triangle t_1 + \mbin n3 \triangle^2\, t_1 + \cdots 
   + \mbin nn \triangle^{n-1}\, t_1.
\end{align}

---

If you carefully compare the book's formulas with these results, you should be able to spot some errors in the book. Where the book says

$$
t_n =
{}^{n-1}C_0\, t_1 + {}^{n-1}C_1\, \triangle t_1
 + {}^{n-1}C_2\, \triangle^2 t_1
 + \cdots + {}^{n-1}C_{r-1}\, \triangle^{r-1} t_1,
$$

the final term should be ${}^{n-1}C_{n-1}\, \triangle^{n-1} t_1$
rather than ${}^{n-1}C_{r-1}\, \triangle^{r-1} t_1$
(that is, the formula should use $n$ rather than $r$, which has no role in this formula),
and where the book says

$$
S_n =
{}^nC_1\, t_1 + {}^nC_2\, \triangle t_1 + {}^nC_3\, \triangle^2 t_1
 + \cdots + {}^nC_r\, \triangle^r t_1,
$$

the final term should be ${}^nC_n\, \triangle^{n-1} t_1$
rather than ${}^nC_r\, \triangle^r t_1$,
that is, again it should use $n$, not $r$, but the superscript of the $\triangle$ symbol should be only $n-1$, not simply replacing $r$ by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the equations so they can be proved as follows. We want to prove $$ t_j=\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{i}\Delta^i t_1\qquad (1)$$
The sum $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n t_j$ expression can be deduced from (1) by inversing the summation order  and noticing $$\sum_{j=i+1}^n \binom{j-1}{i}=\binom{n}{i+1},$$ this can be proved from Pascal's identity ($\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p-1}{q-1}+\binom{p-1}{q}$) and induction.

Back to (1) also by induction. Say $t_j= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{i}\Delta^i t_1$ is true we want $$t_{j+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom{j}{i}\Delta^i t_1=t_1+\sum_{i=1}^{j}\left[\binom{j-1}{i}+\binom{j-1}{i-1}\right]\Delta^i t_1.$$ This equals after writing  $\Delta^i t_1=\Delta^{i-1} t_2-\Delta^{i-1}t_1$ to $$t_1+t_j-t_1-t_j+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{i}\Delta^i t_2$$ which is by induction hypothesis (up to a reindexation) $t_{j+1}$.

Comment: Your versions of the equations in the question are correct, but I would rather have seen the correction made as part of this answer rather than having the equations "fixed" in the question itself. The fact that the equations are wrong in the book (as clearly shown in the photograph; they are not due to transcription errors) is something that I wanted to comment upon, and that is a little awkward now that the incorrect equations are no longer easily seen in the question. As a general rule, I try very hard **not** to correct errors of mathematics when editing questions for better presentation.